# Using Couchbase with Perl Dancer

Tags: couchbase, dancer

Any best practices out there for using Couchbase with Perl Dancer?  I can't seem to find any Dancer-specific plugins anywhere.  Specifically I'm looking for best practices for maintaining persistent database connections, preferably using the native dancer `database` keyword.

I should add, I'm already aware of the `Couchbase::Client` cpan package.  I'm looking for a Dancer-specific equivalent, or any tips/advice on how to properly use `Couchbase::Client` with Dancer.

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with 'Dancer' as of yet but it seems from the [Couchbase::Client](http://search.cpan.org/~mnunberg/Couchbase-Client-1.0.2/lib/Couchbase/Client.pm#Typical_Constructor_Options) that you can have a list of servers to try under the Typical Constructor Options and can then re-try the same server if fails.

Comment: Yes but I'm looking specifically to play well with the Dancer framework for maintaining a persistent pool of connections. I'm thinking about writing a Dancer plugin that in turn depends on Couchbase::Client, but I'm hoping someone else has done the work already :-).

Comment: TCP connections tend to be persistent in general though unless there is explicit intent by either client/server or timeouts and so in this case wouldn't it only be a plugin? Or the specific use case is more complex?